# DropdownMenu inputDecoration isCollapsed property does not reduce vertical spacing

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to remove the vertical spacing in the DropdownMenu here

[image: Dropdown menu with large vertical spacing]

but it does not seem possible by using

```
 DropdownMenu<String>(
        inputDecorationTheme: const InputDecorationTheme(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 5, 0), 
          isCollapsed: true
          ),
          ...
```

I also could not find any other way, could someone help? below the version details.

```
Flutter 3.16.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision db7ef5bf9f (3 days ago) • 2023-11-15 11:25:44 -0800
Engine • revision 74d16627b9
Tools • Dart 3.2.0 • DevTools 2.28.2
```

Comment: This is confirmed to be a flutter issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/138691

Answer (score 0):

One workaround I found is to clip the widget, though is not ideal.

ClipRect(
child: Align(
alignment: Alignment.center,
heightFactor: 0.6,
child: DropdownMenu<>(
...
)
)
)